# Непонятно работает атрибут Remote

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, javascript

Доброго времени суток!:)
столкнулся с такой проблемой. В модели БД  есть полу Mony на него навешен атрибут [Remote (условие)].Все работает на проверку норм, но....если при заполнении формы не снимать фокус с поля куда вводятся данные Mony и нажать на кнопку отправки и отправка происходит только при повторном нажатии на кнопку отправить. Если же фокус снять и перевести на другое поле то все отлично...Где чего надо подправить?:(
За ранее спасибо:)

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно всё понял и имеется ввиду jQuery remote validation  (я правда не знаю что такое Mony), то следующий трюк может вам помочь:

```
$("input[type='text'"]).keypress(function() {
  $(this).valid()
});
```

или

```
//Так можно проверить всю форму
$("input[type='text'"]).keypress(function() {  
  $(this).closest('form').valid()
});
```